# Checking the target window before allowing drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, target

Is there a way to check the **target** (which .exe it belongs to) before allowing the drop ?

What i intend to achieve is allowing a control to be drag & dropped on Word or Excel and depending on which **target** application is, pass the appropriate file.

EDIT:
Here is the code i tried in VB

@David Thanks for the code. I tried similar thing with a Button control (WPF) and adding a file path in the dataobject. Am getting a Stack Imbalance exception.

Here is the code (trying in VB.Net) - this is giving me this error:
A call to PInvoke function 'TestApplication!TestApplication.MainWindow::GetCursorPos' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

did i forget something ?

*EDIT* made a few changes and it works now.

Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Class MainWindow
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
     Private Shared Function WindowFromPoint(ByVal xPoint As Integer, ByVal yPoint As                  Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetCursorPos(lpPoint As Point) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function GetProcessId(hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd As IntPtr, lpdwProcessId As     Integer) As UInteger
    End Function

    Private MouseIsDown As Boolean = Nothing

    Private Sub DropButton_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles DropButton.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown
        MouseIsDown = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub DropButton_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DropButton.MouseMove
        If MouseIsDown Then
            Dim data As New DataObject()
            Dim DropList As New StringCollection
            DropList.Add("c:\file.txt")
            data.SetFileDropList(DropList)
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(CType(e.OriginalSource, DependencyObject), data, DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub DropButton_GiveFeedback(sender As Object, e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles DropButton.GiveFeedback
    Dim a = Mouse.GetPosition(Me)
    If a <> Nothing Then

        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = WindowFromPoint(a.X, a.Y)

        If hWnd <> Nothing Then
            Dim processId As Integer
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, processId)

            Dim proc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(processId)
            label1.Content = proc.MainWindowTitle
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can get this by implementing some interop in the GiveFeedback event for the control that is performing the drag/drop operation. I made a sample app and used a treeview control and a label on a form to test with.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point Point);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetProcessId(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);


private void treeView1_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    Point p;

    if (GetCursorPos(out p))
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(p);

        if (hWnd != null)
        {
            int processId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);

            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            label1.Text = proc.MainWindowTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am just showing the Window Title in my example. You can get the application .exe name using proc.MainModule.FileName.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that you've already had to tell the DragDrop what your data object was, I don't see any way to change it. I guess you could save the file of the correct type to a file with no extension each time that the receiving app changed from the givefeedback.

Comment: @David Thanks for the code. I tried similar thing with a Button control (WPF) and adding a file path in the dataobject. Am getting a Stack Imbalance exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the paradigm works in reverse of what you want. You have to specify what you have available. Then the application you drop it on has the choice of what it wants to take.

Unfortunately, if you put multiple files in a DataFormats.FileDrop, Excel will open both files (I assume that Word will also).

Also, for excel (and I assume word), where/when you drop it changes it's preference, for instance:

- If you drop when Excel has no files open it prefers FileDrop, denys everything else
- If you drop on the title bar, it prefers FileDrop, denys everything else
- If you drop on an open sheet, it prefers StringFormat (even though I thought it would prefer CSV)
- How ever Excel does prefer Rtf to CSV, so if you put both in your data, Word would take the Rtf and Excel would take the CSV

So, the code to do this is...

```
  DataObject d = new DataObject();
  d.SetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, csvValue);
  d.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, rtfValue);
  DoDragDrop(d, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

So, if you could convert your data into csv and rtf formats prior to the call, it would pass the data. I couldn't find anyway to do this using files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose what clipboard format to render at drop time, you have to delay the rendering of the content until the drop happen by [implementing IASyncOperation/IDataObjectAsyncCapability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/04/creating-something-from-nothing-asynchronously-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net-improved.aspx). But there is no documentation from Office about how it identify itself to your drag source. There's a DDWM_UPDATEWINDOW message from the Windows team, however I am not sure the office team use it.

Generally speaking, [each program have its own preference of clipboard formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255916/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-checking-the-target-window-before-allowing-drop). For example if your IDataObject::GetData got called with [WordML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212812%28v=office.11%29.aspx), then the target is probably Microsoft Word. If [SpreadsheetML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb226687%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is preferred, then the target is probably Microsoft Excel. You don't need to actually provide the content for those two formats but you can use the pattern of clipboard formats queried to determine what kind of program your data is dropped to, and provide the data at a later time, for example, when CF_HTML is queried. Of course if you don't mind wasting some memory, you don't need IASyncOperation, just fill the data object with formats that are not shared between Word and Excel, Word would pick the first format it understands, and Excel will pick the first format it understands.